# How to call Ajax on drop down in CakePHP

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I am new to PHP and CakePHP. I m trying to call Ajax on changing drop down item. I have done it for a link as below code

```
echo $this->Html->link('TestLink', array('controller'=>'Tutors','action'=>'getData',$iid), array('class'=>'js-ajax'));
```

but unable to apply on drop down. I have used the code for drop down as below

```
echo $this->Form->input('My City', array('empty'=>'Select City','options' => $cities));
```

here, where to put code to call ajax.
Please help.

Comment: Live examples for AJAX in CakePHP can be found [here](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax_examples/) by the way including code examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind an ajax event to `js-ajax`

```
$('.js-ajax').on('change', function(){
  // do some ajax here.
});
```

`

Comment: I want to add its related code on echo $this->Form->input('My City', array('empty'=>'Select City','options' => $cities));

Answer (score 1):

If its just the selector you're looking to add to trigger the ajax, then do the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('My City', array(
                                 'empty'=>'Select City',
                                 'options' => $cities,
                                 'class' => 'js-ajax'
                        ));
```

Then you can have your javascript onchange called with this selector

Comment: Its helpful for me...and also need to pass cityid to js function. how to pass ?

Comment: then, like in Alex M's answer, when you call `$('.js-ajax').on('change', function(){
  // do some ajax here.
});` where //do some ajax here is, you can extract the value using `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use jquery to do this?

put in your webroot and call in your layout(app/view/layouts)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //your code
    $("#youFieldId").change(function(){
        //Your logic
    });


});
```